# How to include c++ libraries so that node-gyp can link?

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp

I am writing nodejs code and want to use C++ code (backend.cpp which includes 'mysql/mysql.h')  using node-gyp to compile. I am getting this error while building:

module.js:356
  Module.*extensions[extension](this, filename);
                               ^
Error:* ____/build/Release/backend.node: undefined symbol: mysql_init

Can anyone help? How can I instruct node-gyp to link mysql.h to the target backend.node?

Answer (score 2):

Have you added it in the `libraries` list in your binding.gyp file?

Here's a short example:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "backend",
      "sources": [<comma separated source names>],
      "include_dirs":[<comma separated include dirs>],
      "libraries": [<comma separated library paths>]
    }
  ]
}
```

You should also take a look at the complete [Gyp Language Specification](http://code.google.com/p/gyp/wiki/GypLanguageSpecification)