# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found. Expected in: flat namespace

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp

I'm trying to create own c++ addon to node from code that was written by my collegue.

It compiles to `file.node` and then it crashes when I try to use it in node.

I have tried to prebuild library, then use `library.dylib` and also to build it together by node-gyp.

Both of these approaches compile and throw an error on runtime.

What else can I do?

I'm working on OSX Mojave.

I've checked:

> [How to include c++ libraries so that node-gyp can link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145249/how-to-include-c-libraries-so-that-node-gyp-can-link)
>
> [dyld: lazy symbol binding failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904313/dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed)

Whole error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: 
__ZN3mds7computeERNSt3__16vectorINS1_IdNS0_9allocatorIdEEEENS2_IS4_EEEE
Referenced from: /.../node_folder/build/release/file.node
Expected in: flat namespace
```

My gyp file:

```
{
  "targets": [
     {
       "target_name": "name",
       "sources": ["file.cc"],
       "include_dirs": [
         "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")",
         "/path/to/cpp/src/"
       ],
       "link_settings": {
         "libraries": ["-L/path/to/dylib/directory"]
       },
       "libraries": ["-L/path/to/dylib/directory"]
    }
  ]
}
```

My package.json

```
{
 ...
 "dependencies": {
   "nan": "^2.12.1",
   "node-gyp": "^3.8.0"
 },
 "scripts": {
   "compile": "node-gyp rebuild",
   "start": "node index.js"
 },
 "gypfile": true
}
```

My binding file:

```
#include <nan.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <my_header_file.h>

using namespace v8;

NAN_METHOD(compute)
{
    if (!info[0]->IsArray())
    {
        Nan::ThrowTypeError("Argument myst be an array");
        return;
    }
    ...

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vector;
     
    ... (filling the vector with data)

    //static std::vector<std::vector<double>> compute(std::vector<std::vector<double>> & distances_matrix);
    mds::compute(vector);
}

NAN_MODULE_INIT(Initialize)
{
    NAN_EXPORT(target, compute);
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, Initialize);
```

Comment: Can you demangle: `__ZN3mds7computeERNSt3__16vectorINS1_IdNS0_9allocatorIdEEEENS2_IS4_EEEE` please?  You obviously have a missing symbol.  Knowing what it is might make the fix obvious.

Comment: @MartinBonner I've edited cpp code -> I've added the method that I think throws it.

Comment: @MartinBonner How can we demangle symbols? Is there a tool for that?

Comment: https://demangler.com @Jonathan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see you are importing your header at `#include <my_header_file.h>`. 
If you are calling a method from your custom class for your NAN_METHOD you need to call it inline or else the compiler will not know where to look.

Run "c++filt (missing symbol)" to demangle and see where you need to call it

**Example**
Instead of `method()`
Use `Class::method()`

Your missing symbol demangled is `mds::compute(std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >&)`

Comment: This fixed my problem. Just to be clearer for other users: in your class body, `Napi::Value method(...) {}` should become `Napi::Value ClassName::method(...) {}`

Answer (score 2):

I have solved from https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1380,

> The missing symbol's name indicates it's not using C linkage.

I just add *extern "C"* in the header file

```
extern "C" double add(double a ,double b);
```